# REST API : Magento 2 : Without admin token how i can registered new user?

Tags: magento2, customer, api, rest-api, registration

I am using bearer token for rest API authentication in Magento2.3.2 but I am facing one issue, while registering the new user, admin authentication token is required while registering New user by API. So my question is how I can register new user with authentication?

Comment: Hi @VishalBansal can you please add your code.

Comment: With or without admin token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at `vendor/magento/module-customer/etc/webapi.xml`

```
<route url="/V1/customers" method="POST">
    <service class="Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface" method="createAccount"/>
    <resources>
        <resource ref="anonymous"/>
    </resources>
</route>
```

As we can see, we can create a new customer account without token.

Comment: I want to reg. with token but don't go with admin token , is this possible by customer token?

Comment: Why do we need token?